# API path is changed when updated to newest nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a problem, updated my app to newest nextjs (13.1.6), however all my request ar failing now. Somehow, the URL I set up in the request creator, based on the ENV value, is getting overwritten.

```
.env file
CONST NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL = 'HTTPS://API.COM';

requestCreator file
const response = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);
```

Before updating, the requests were sent properly to URL:

```
https://api.com/some-path
```

But after nextjs update, the requests are being sent to:

```
http://localhost:3000/_next/data/development/en/some-path
```

Why does this happen? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To expose env to the browser his name should started with NEXT_PUBLIC_.
But this rule old enough. Maybe you used very old Next version

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: Sorry, my env variable is named this way. I didnt know it was important. Edited my question.

Comment: Try to reproduce your code at codesandbox. Not enough information to solve problem